# First instance 0 rest other become 1 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario where IF `ID`, `Code` and `InsertDate` is same and if it is 1st entry then it will be 0 else 1.

Demo data:

```
CREATE TABLE #test 
(
     ID int,
     code int,
     InsertDate datetime2
)

Insert into #test values (1,1,'2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000')
Insert into #test values (1,1,'2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000')
Insert into #test values (1,1,'2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000')
Insert into #test values (2,1,'2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000')
Insert into #test values (3,1,'2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000')
```

Expected o/p

```
ID  code    InsertDate              flag   
-----------------------------------------
1    1  2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000  0     
1    1  2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000  1     
1    1  2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000  1     
2    1  2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000  0     
3    1  2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000  0
```

What I tried

```
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Code, Insertdate ORDER BY InsertDate) flag 
FROM #test
```

With this I got the initial logic but what to do next I need help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple `CASE` expression may help:

```
SELECT
   *,
   CASE 
      WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Code, Insertdate ORDER BY InsertDate) = 1 THEN 0 
      ELSE 1 
   END AS Flag
FROM #test
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
Create table #test (ID int,code int,InsertDate datetime2)

Insert into #test values (1,1,'2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000')
Insert into #test values (1,1,'2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000')
Insert into #test values (1,1,'2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000')
Insert into #test values (2,1,'2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000')
Insert into #test values (3,1,'2019-09-17 03:19:00.0000000')

with cte as (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID,Code,Insertdate order by InsertDate) as RowNumber,
        ID,
        code,
        InsertDate
    FROM #test
)
SELECT 
    ID,
    code,
    InsertDate, 
    IIF(RowNumber = 1,0,1) as flag
FROM cte
```

Also here is shorter version you can use:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    code,
    InsertDate,
    IIF(ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID,Code,Insertdate order by InsertDate) = 1,0,1) as Flag
FROM #test
```

Answer (score 2):

Different route, you could use `SIGN`, which returns `-1` for negative numbers, `0` for `0`, and `1` for positive numbers:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       code,
       InsertDate,
       SIGN(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, code, InsertDate ORDER BY InsertDate) - 1) AS flag
FROM #test;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9075c0f00ebbcbac80ad5f62955d5f9e)